# Searching by tag, inclusive

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a many to many relationship between `stories` and `tags`, the table created to hold the relationship is `taxonomies`. I want to search all the stories that have all the given tags.

The query I'm using so far is this one, of course it doesn't work for me, it returns all stories that contain **any** of the given tags, I want to show stories that contain **all** the defined tags.

```
 SELECT stories.* FROM `stories` 
 JOIN `taxonomies` ON `stories`.id = `taxonomies`.`story_id`
 JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.id = `taxonomies`.tag_id
 WHERE `tags`.name = 'tag 1' OR `tags`.name = 'tag 2' /* ... */
 GROUP BY stories.id
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using OR to compare instead of AND?

Comment: How do you want to accomplish getting "stories that contain all the defined tags" if the some of the tags are mutually exclusive?  Perhaps there is something more about the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this query

```
SELECT stories.id FROM `stories` 
 JOIN `taxonomies` ON `stories`.id = `taxonomies`.`story_id`
 JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.id = `taxonomies`.tag_id
 GROUP BY stories.id
 HAVING SUM(`tags`.name = 'tag 1')>0
 AND SUM(`tags`.name = 'tag 2')>0
```

Comment: @gosukiwi Opps I had a mistake,fixed it.The WHERE was not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the number of tags you are checking?  If so, could you use a [HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) to confirm that the number of matches for `stories.id` matches the total number of tags?  Something like this:

```
SELECT stories.id, COUNT(stories.id)
FROM `stories` 
 JOIN `taxonomies` ON `stories`.id = `taxonomies`.`story_id`
 JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.id = `taxonomies`.tag_id
 WHERE `tags`.name = 'tag 1' OR `tags`.name = 'tag 2' /* ... */
 GROUP BY stories.id
HAVING COUNT(stories.id) = @numberOfTags
```

Comment: Just be sure not to have duplicate tags.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way to do this will be:

```
 SELECT stories.* FROM `stories` 
 JOIN `taxonomies` ON `stories`.id = `taxonomies`.`story_id`
 JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.id = `taxonomies`.tag_id
 WHERE `tags`.name = 'tag 1'
 GROUP BY stories.id
intersect
 SELECT stories.* FROM `stories` 
 JOIN `taxonomies` ON `stories`.id = `taxonomies`.`story_id`
 JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.id = `taxonomies`.tag_id
 WHERE `tags`.name = 'tag 2'
 GROUP BY stories.id
```

Comment: Mysql does not have intersect ,i suppose you come from oracle